# Mysql query INSERT two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:`table1` and `rating`

```
table1(id,name,category) 
rating (cid,rating,total_rating,total_rates,photoID)
```

and now when i insert data into table1 i want to set all data in table rating at zero for that specific photoID from table1, but i dont know how..can someone help me?

Comment: Not really getting. Do you want to transfer data from rating to tabbl1 or ? Else please elaborate this want to set all data in table rating at zero

Comment: setting ALL data in rating as zero? is that really what you mean? Or do you mean insert a new row in the rating table with rating  = zero corresponding to the new data you added in table1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to retrieve the ID you just inserted.  For example, assuming `PhotoID` is the relation between `table1` and `rating`:

```
insert table1 (name,category) values ('waterfall 2', 'nature');
insert rating (rating,total_rating,total_rates,photoID) values
    (0, 0, 0, last_insert_id());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather create a `STORED PROCEDURE` to make a single call from application. Assuming that you want to `INSERT` a record on table `rating` for every insert on `table1` and that `ID` on `table1` is set as `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureName
(
    IN _name VARCHAR(25),
    IN _category VARCHAR(25)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table1 (name, category)
    VALUES (_name, _category);

    SET @last_ID := LAST_INSERT_ID();

    INSERT INTO rating (cid, rating, total_rating, total_rates, photoID)
    VALUES (@last_ID, 0,0,0,0);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and call the procedure,

```
CALL procedureName('nameHere','categoryHere')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySql triggers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_rating AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO rating (cid,rating,total_rating,total_rates,photoID)
         VALUES( NEW.ID ,0,0,0,null)
END;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `before insert` result in a foreign key violation here?

Comment: Thanks @Andomar, changed it to `after insert`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert data into TABLE1 and delete it from TABLE2, you can write below listed query:

```
mysql_query("DELETE * FROM table2");
```

Comment: i dont want to delete i want to set rating at zero for that specific id